# Index page is not rendered with newly saved data

Tags: node.js, express, couchbase

I'm using the following technologies and frameworks versions:

- Couchbase:  Enterprise Edition 6.0.1 build 2037 ‧ IPv4
- Node: v10.15.3
- Express: v4.16.4

I'm a beginner with this technologies and frameworks.

I'm making a simple app with Node + Express and I'm using Couchbase to save data.
The app is about courses and students, and which student take  which courses and which course has which students.
Everything works fine, I can Save, Delete, looking for details, just I have a small issue:

I save new data (doesn't matter that it is on the course route or on the students route), than my app redirect to the index page and it suppose to show all the courses or students. It shows the previously saved students or courses, but not contains the newly saved student or course. When I refresh the page (F5) than it shows the newly saved student or course.
It has to show the newly saved student or course without refreshing the index page.

here is my code

how I'm saving to the DB and redirecting to the /courses route:

```
//save new course in the db than redirect to index page
app.post("/courses", function(request, response) {
    var course = new CourseModel({
        "name": request.body.name
    });
    course.save(function(error, result) {
        if(error) {
            return response.status(401).send({ "success": false, "message": error});
        }
        response.redirect("/courses");
    });
});
```

and this is how the /courses route looks like:

```
//get all courses and render index page
app.get("/courses", function(request, response) {
    CourseModel.find({}, {load: ["students"]}, function(error, result) {
        if(error) {
            return response.status(401).send({ "success": false, "message": error});
        }
        response.render("courses/index", {results: result});
    });
});
```

So when I hit the SAVE button, than It should save to the db than redirect to the /courses page, where it should render the index page contains the newly saved course or student but it doesn't. But after refreshing the page the newly saved course or student is there.

So why the newly saved data is not there immediately on the index page? What should I change ?

My Couchbase Server is running locally on my computer with this cluster and bucket settings:

Type: Couchbase
Bucket RAM Quota: 512MB
Cluster RAM Quota: 4.1GB
Replicas: 1
Server Nodes: 1
Ejection Method: Value-Only
Conflict Resolution: Sequence Number
Compaction: Not active

Answer (score 0):

try to use 205 status code int the HTTP response, this means reset content but this will be helpful if you're using google chrome browser

cause the rest of the browser handles 205 code like 200 both are a success but without resetting the content

you can have more information about the 205 from this [link](https://httpstatuses.com/205)

Comment: if I modify the resopnse in app.get like that : response.status(205).render...  (I'm using Chrome) than the screen doesnt change, however in Inspect/Network I can see that the post request was sent, than redirect to /courses, but nothing happening on the screen.